# configure NGINX: for Wordpress Headless with nextjs

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I want to make a WordPress Headless (using wpgraphql API at /graphql uri), where frontend will be next.js. And I want both the front-end (Next.js) and the back-end (WordPress. admin, content, and API) to be in the **same domain**.

To that end I want all requests only for `/wp-admin/*` and `/wp-content/*` and `/graphql` to be directed to WordPress. And all other uri's will be redirected to the next.js server in localhost:3000 via reverse proxy.
Below is the nginx configuration file.

```yaml
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  root /var/www/wordpress;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name localhost;

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  autoindex off;

  # WordPress 
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  # Next.js
  location # ... {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx uses the longest matching prefix specified with `location` directive. Therefore the following setup should do what you want.

You can take the following approach:

```
  location /wp-admin {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  
  location /wp-includes {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
    
  location /wp-json {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location /wp-content {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location /graphql {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
```

Comment: Works great, but the `wp-includes` and `wp-json` paths must be added. Thanks